# Workbench MySQL: table is not editable

Tags: mysql, workbench

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE `cat_matches` (
  `from_cat` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `to_cat` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `tag` char(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`),
  KEY `cat_matches_ibfk_1` (`from_cat`),
  KEY `cat_matches_ibfk_2` (`to_cat`),
  CONSTRAINT `cat_matches_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`from_cat`) REFERENCES `category` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `cat_matches_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`to_cat`) REFERENCES `category` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2519 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

In a lot of other threads, people reply "in Workbench the table have to have a PK to be editable". But as you can see, this table contains a column called id which is the PK, and is still not editable. Why?

Comment: Note that if you have a primary key referencing a set of columns, it is entirely redundant to have a unique key referencing the same set.  A primary key implies a unique constraint.

Comment: Yes, Ok, UNIQUE KEY is a remnant from a previous version of the table. Since it's redundant I just left it there. But yes, it'd be cleaner to remove it.

Comment: Are you connecting as a user with UPDATE privileges on the table?

Comment: Thanks for checking, I tested that as well, and for what it's worth even when I connect as a user without INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE privileges, it still allows me to edit a row, but when I click Apply it gives me errors because I lack the privs.

Comment: If the row is not editable, there is supposed to be an icon in the lower right of the pane. It has a label "read only" and a little (i) icon. The manual says you can hover over the icon and a tooltip explains why it's read only. But I just tested that and I see no tooltip (using Workbench 6.1.6).

Comment: @BillKarwin Exactly.